# Issue with printing 2D array of structs with "\n"

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct, printf

I'm trying to print a 2D array of structs using printf in a box formation.  Each struct holds an int and char value.  When I try to print them it prints the int value just fine, but instead of printing the char value it prints �.  When I remove the printf statement telling them to go to a new line after the second for loop(printf("\n")) finishes it prints just fine(except for the fact that it's not in a box formation.  Is this some weird quark of C or am I overlooking something?

```
for(int i = 0; i < States-1; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
        printf("%d%c  ", mArray[i][j].state, mArray[i][j].action);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  
99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  
99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  
99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�  99�
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "classes.h"

void corUsage(argc)
{
        if(argc == 1)
        {
                printf("usage: ./tokenize tm_file\n");
                exit(1);
        }

}

int curState = 0;
char curAction = 0;

void maketok(char *str)
{

        char *ptr = str;
        ptr = strtok(str, "/");
        curState = atoi(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        curAction = ptr;
//      printf("%d / %s",curState, curAction);
}

struct Matrix
{
{
        int state;
        char action;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    corUsage(argc);

    //opens the file given(argc[1])
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    //checks for errors
    if(fp == NULL)
    {//error occured
            perror(argv[1]);
            exit(1);
    }
    char buffer[256];//a buffer that holds stuff

    char *ptr = buffer;//a pointer to the buffer
    char *ptr2;//a pointer for MISC.

    int States;//The number of states
    int Start;//The starting state
    int Accept;//The ending state


    //this reads the first three lines of the tm.x file and stores
    //it in the variable above.
    ptr = fgets(buffer, 256, fp);
    ptr2 = strtok(ptr, " ");
    ptr2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    States = atoi(ptr2);
    ptr = fgets(buffer, 256, fp);
    ptr2 = strtok(ptr, " ");
    ptr2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    Start = atoi(ptr2);
    ptr = fgets(buffer, 256, fp);
    ptr2 = strtok(ptr, " ");
    ptr2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    Accept = atoi(ptr2);

    struct Matrix mArray[States][12];//a 2D array that will be holding structs

    while((ptr = fgets(buffer, 256, fp)) != NULL)
    {
            char *cur = strtok(ptr, " ");
            int idx = atoi(cur);
            char *buffer2[256];//a buffer for MISC data
            int co = 0;//counter vairable that tells how many things are in the line.
            for(cur = strtok(NULL, " "); cur != NULL; cur = strtok(NULL, " "))
            {
                    buffer2[co] = cur;//possibily not co as index?
                    co++;
            }
            for(int q = 0; q < 12; q++)
            {
                    struct Matrix var;
                    var.state = 99;
                    var.action = "d";
                    mArray[idx][q] = var;
            }
            /*for(int i = 0; i < co; i++)
            {

                            maketok(buffer2[i]);
                            printf("%d / %s", curState, curAction);
                            mArray[idx][i].state = curState;
                            mArray[idx][i].action = curAction;

            }*/

            for(int i = 0; i < States-1; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
                            printf("%d%c  ", mArray[i][j].state, mArray[i][j].action);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
            }

}
```

File that I'm reading in:

```
states 10
start  0
accept 9
0  0/0d  1/0d  2/1s  3/3s  4/2s  5/2s  6/5s  7/4s  8/4s  10/9d
1  0/9d  1/9d  2/1s  3/1s  4/1s  5/1s  10/9d
2  0/9d  1/9d  3/2s  4/2s  5/2s  10/9d
3  0/9d  1/9d  3/3s  4/3s  5/9d  10/9d
4  0/9d  1/9d  10/9d
5  0/9d  1/9d  7/6s  10/9d
6  0/6s  1/6s  2/6s  3/6s  4/6s  5/6s  6/6s  7/7s  8/6s  9/6s  10/9d
7  0/6s  1/6s  2/6s  3/6s  4/6s  5/6s  6/8s  7/7s  8/6s  9/6s  10/9d
8  0/9d  1/9d  10/9d
```

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Comment: Please post complete code along with the variation of print loop you talked of.

Comment: What's in the file you're reading?

Comment: So I figured out that if I replace the print("\n") with gets("") it fixes the problem, but I still don't know why it does this.

Comment: Replacing a `printf()` (presumably) with a `gets()` and a constant string argument seems more likely to cause trouble than cure it.  Your question would be more convincing if the code were compilable: `struct Matrix { { int state; …` is not valid C.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler,  I agree, the code does not compile due to the syntax error in the struct definition.

Comment: The separation between the data in the input file (per the post) is delimited by two spaces, not just one, so the actual value(s) being read in are not what the code is expecting.

Comment: @user3629249: are you sure about the multiple spaces being a problem?  The code is tokenized with `strtok()` which handles multiple separators with ease.

Comment: Given this as an example line from the file: 4  0/9d  1/9d  10/9d, the reading of the data in the code does not match the format of the actual data.  Correction of the reading of the data (and for clarity, try commenting which field the code thinks it is reading) would eliminate most all the problems.

Comment: this line: mArray[idx][q] = var; does not copy the struct.  what is needed is something more like memcpy( &(mArray[idx][q]), &var, sizeof( struct Matrix ) );

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out.

in this loop:

```
for(int q = 0; q < 12; q++)
        {
                struct Matrix var;
                var.state = 99;
                var.action = "d";
                mArray[idx][q] = var;
        }
```

I declare `var.action = "d";`.
It should be `var.action = 'd';` in single quotes only.

Thank you to anyone who took the time to look at this.

Comment: That would have most likely given you a warning in compile time, since you were assigning a `char*` to a `char`. If you have a good look at the warnings, you'll become less prone to such issues.

Comment: If the compiler was not warning you about that assignment, you need to turn on the compilation warnings, or get a better compiler. Remember, while you're learning C (and probably even longer), the compiler knows more about C than you do.  If it gives a warning, it means there is something dubious about your program, and you should heed its warning and fix your code.  You'll know when you know enough to ignore the compiler warnings — and it won't be while you need to ask questions like this one.  (I routinely compile with `gcc -g -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror` plus some extras.)